# Is epoll thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, epoll

There are two functions in epoll:

1. epoll_ctl
2. epoll_wait

Are they **thread-safe** when I use the same epoll_fd?

What will happen if one thread calls epoll_wait and others call epoll_ctl at the same time?

Comment: do you use the same epoll_fd ?

Comment: yes, I use the same epoll_fd.

Comment: Can you give more details about your usage?  Why do you have to use the same epoll fd?  If you are doing an RX/TX structure, you can have one epoll fd corrsepond to the IN events and one correspond to the out events (this is what I use in a few apps)

Comment: Hi, I use epll io multiplexing with the thread pool, and I want to use epoll_ctl to change the events on other threads. But I do not know whether I need to use some synchronization mechanism to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is thread-safe, but there isn't much documentation that explicitly states that.  See [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/2/28/367)

BTW, you can also have multiple threads waiting on a single `epoll_fd`, but in that case it can get a bit tricky.  (I.e. you might want to use edge-triggered `EPOLLET` or oneshot mode `EPOLLONESHOT`.  See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_ctl).)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is thread-safe according to the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html#NOTES) for `epoll_wait`. It explicitly allows adding a file descriptor to an epoll set while it is being waited for in another thread:

Section "Notes":

> While one thread is blocked in a call to **epoll_wait()**, it is possible
> for another thread to add a file descriptor to the waited-upon **epoll**
> instance.  If the new file descriptor becomes ready, it will cause the
> **epoll_wait()** call to unblock.