# Is rearming file descriptors for epoll thread safe?

Tags: event-handling, epoll, epollet

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058737/is-epoll-thread-safe) I know that I can call `epoll_ctl(2)` while another thread is blocking on `epoll_wait(2)`. I still have a question though.

When using `epoll` with the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag only one event is fired and the fd has to be rearmed using `epoll_ctl(2)`. This is necessary so only one thread
will read from the fd and handle the result appropriately.

The following is a timeline that somewhat visualizes my supposed problem:

```
Thread1:                       Thread2:                  Kernel:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
epoll_wait();
                                                         Receives chunk
dispatch chunk to thread 2
epoll_wait();                  Handle chunk
                               Still handle chunk        Receives chunk
                               Rearm fd for epoll
?
```

What happens on the question mark when the fd is rearmed after a chunk is received? Will `epoll` fire an `EPOLLIN` event, or will it block indefinitely although the socket is readable? Is my architecture at all sensible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your architecture is sensible, and it will work: `epoll` will mark the file descriptor as readable and fire an `EPOLLIN` event.

The documentation on this is scarce and subtle; the Q/A section of `man 7 epoll` briefly mentions this:

> Q8 Does an operation on a file descriptor affect the already collected
>   but not yet reported events?
>
> A8 You can do two operations on an
>   existing file descriptor. Remove would be meaningless for this case.
>   Modify will reread available I/O.

The two operations that you can do on an existing file descriptor (an existing file descriptor is a file descriptor that has been added to the epoll set in the past - this includes file descriptors that are waiting to be rearmed) are delete and modify. As the manpage mentions, delete is meaningless here, and modify will re-evaluate the conditions in the file descriptor.

Nothing beats a real world experiment though. The following program tests this edge case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static pthread_t tids[2];
static int epoll_fd;
static char input_buff[512];
static sem_t chunks_sem;

void *dispatcher(void *arg) {
    struct epoll_event epevent;

    while (1) {
        printf("Dispatcher waiting for more chunks\n");
        if (epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &epevent, 1, -1) < 0) {
            perror("epoll_wait(2) error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ssize_t n;
        if ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, input_buff, sizeof(input_buff)-1)) <= 0) {
            if (n < 0)
                perror("read(2) error");
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "stdin closed prematurely\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        input_buff[n] = '\0';
        sem_post(&chunks_sem);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    sigset_t smask;
    sigemptyset(&smask);
    sigaddset(&smask, SIGUSR1);

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&chunks_sem);
        printf("Consumer received chunk: %s", input_buff);
        /* Simulate some processing... */
        sleep(2);
        printf("Consumer finished processing chunk.\n");
        printf("Please send SIGUSR1 after sending more data to stdin\n");

        int signo;
        if (sigwait(&smask, &signo) < 0) {
            perror("sigwait(3) error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        assert(signo == SIGUSR1);

        struct epoll_event epevent;
        epevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT;
        epevent.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;

        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, STDIN_FILENO, &epevent) < 0) {
            perror("epoll_ctl(2) error when attempting to readd stdin");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Readded stdin to epoll fd\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {

    sigset_t sigmask;
    sigfillset(&sigmask);
    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &sigmask, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("pthread_sigmask(3) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((epoll_fd = epoll_create(1)) < 0) {
        perror("epoll_create(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct epoll_event epevent;
    epevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT;
    epevent.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &epevent) < 0) {
        perror("epoll_ctl(2) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sem_init(&chunks_sem, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("sem_init(3) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pthread_create(&tids[0], NULL, dispatcher, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("pthread_create(3) error on dispatcher");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pthread_create(&tids[1], NULL, consumer, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("pthread_create(3) error on consumer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(tids)/sizeof(tids[0]); i++) {
        if (pthread_join(tids[i], NULL) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_join(3) error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works as follows: the dispatcher thread adds `stdin` to an epoll set and then uses `epoll_wait(2)` to fetch input from `stdin` whenever it becomes readable. When input arrives, the dispatcher wakes up the worker thread, who prints the input and simulates some processing time by sleeping 2 seconds. In the meantime, the dispatcher goes back to the main loop and blocks in `epoll_wait(2)` again.

The worker thread won't rearm `stdin` until you tell it to by sending it `SIGUSR1`. So, we just write some more stuff into `stdin`, and then send `SIGUSR1` to the process. The worker thread receives the signal, and only then it rearms `stdin` - which is already readable by that time, and the dispatcher was already waiting on `epoll_wait(2)`.

You can see from the output that the dispatcher is correctly awaken and everything works like a charm:

```
Dispatcher waiting for more chunks
testing 1 2 3 // Input
Dispatcher waiting for more chunks // Dispatcher notified worker and is waiting again
Consumer received chunk: testing 1 2 3
Consumer finished processing chunk.
Please send SIGUSR1 after sending more data to stdin
hello world // Input
Readded stdin to epoll fd // Rearm stdin; dispatcher is already waiting
Dispatcher waiting for more chunks // Dispatcher saw new input and is now waiting again
Consumer received chunk: hello world
Consumer finished processing chunk.
Please send SIGUSR1 after sending more data to stdin
```