# Is epoll_ctl() safe to be called simultaneously from multiple threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Assuming I have the epoll instance `mEPoll`, can I safely add (via `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`) or remove (via `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`) a socket handle via

```
struct epoll_event event;
event.data.fd = newFD;
event.events = eventmask;
epoll_ctl(mEPoll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newFD, &event);
```

...simultaneously from multiple threads, or do I need to add my own synchronisation primitive around `epoll_ctl`?

**EDIT:**

It has been suggested that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058737/is-epoll-thread-safe) answers my question here.  However, that question seems to focus on whether it is safe to call `epoll_ctl` whilst waiting on `epoll_wait`: I already know that is safe.  This question is purely asking about whether I can simultaneously make two calls to `epoll_ctl` and not run into problems.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that I can't find anything about it in the manpages now that you ask, but I've always assumed that it is, and written programs accordingly, because what would be the alternative? It's not like the kernel can allow itself to let its internal epoll object data become ill-defined just because from user-space requests.

Comment: Thanks, and I agree.  However I'd really like some concrete proof stating that its thread safe...

Comment: Looking at the kernel source code, it does certainly hold a mutex inside `epoll_ctl` around all the modifications being done to the internal structures. That doesn't translate to a strict external contract, of course, but nevertheless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is epoll thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058737/is-epoll-thread-safe)

Comment: I disagree, this question is different: see my edit please.