# Why is epoll thread-safe but not libevent

Tags: multithreading, epoll, libevent

I am a bit confused about the difference between epoll and libevent.
Libevent is just an encapsulation of epoll.

Since epoll is considered to be thread-safe (e.g. [Is epoll thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058737/is-epoll-thread-safe) [Is epoll_ctl() safe to be called simultaneously from multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442052/is-epoll-ctl-safe-to-be-called-simultaneously-from-multiple-threads)), why does libevent become thread-unsafe?

Which part of libevent breaks its thread-safety?

Comment: "why does libevent become thread-unsafe?" - because `libevent` adds a *metric tonne* of new functionality on-top of the POSIX multithreading primitives.